# On this event go to this url , else go here

Tags: php, redirect, if-statement

I am trying to write an if statment in php but I am not sure how to redirect the user to another url on a condition.
What I am trying to do is :

```
 if $member = $notmember
 go here index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=6&Itemid=174
else
go here index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=6&Itemid=124
```

I am not sure how to redirect to another url though ?.

Comment: It's all about the `header()` function, and it's covered on the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) with an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `header`. Something like this:

```
if ($member == $notmember)
   header("Location: index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=6&Itemid=174");
else
   header("Location: index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=6&Itemid=124");
```

If after the `else`, you have more code, you should use  `exit()`  in order to prevent of your code to keep executing.

Have a look at the PHP official [website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). And especially take notice to the following:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to `exit()`? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use header():

```
<?php
if ($member == $notmember) {
   header("Location: http://xx.com");
   exit;
} else {
   header("Location: http://yy.com");
   exit;
}
?>
```

Don't forget **exit**, otherwise the rest of you php script will be executed.

For more information about the header function see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Is it possible to call two headers at once, a bit like launching two web pages ?

Comment: You mean in two different windows then? I think this has to be done with Javascript.

Comment: You get a plus one for including the `exit` and explanation for exit.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( $member == $notmember) // use TWO equals signs, otherwise you're just assigning
    header("Location: index.php.......");
else
    header("Location: index.php.......");
exit; // stop script execution
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($member == $notmember) {?>
<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=6&Itemid=174"</script>
<?php } else {?>
<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=6&Itemid=124"</script>
<?php } ?>
```

this is php w/ js solution

Comment: What if the user doesn't have Javascript enabled?

Comment: Then this will be useless. I imagine that the day all mankind disable js own browsers.. We are closing to this point, although js frameworks are spreading.

Comment: The percentage of users that have in enabled is large, but there are special circumstances (people that use NoScript) so you can't always rely on Javascript support being there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this too:

```js
if ($member == $notmember)
  echo "<script>window.location = 'index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=6&Itemid=124";
else
  echo "<script>window.location = 'index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=6&Itemid=124'</script>";
```