# Redirect to another page php if and else statement

Tags: php, html

Hey i want to redirect to the same page on my if and else statement. How would i do it?

I tried the following code but didnt work:

```
if($ac == 'yes'){
    $message="Demo sold their product";
    header( "Location: delete/delete.product.php?product=<?php echo $encodeCodeProduct; ?>" ); die;
} else{
    $message="Demo did not sell their product";
    header( "Location: delete/delete.product.php?product=<?php echo $encodeCodeProduct; ?>" ); die;
}
```

Comment: Did now work how? Also, if you redirect to the same page, how does it know that there was a redirect? How is it going to respond differently? Variables like `$ac` and `$message` are deleted at the end of the run, so the redirected page starts with a blank set of variables. You'd have to use a session to remember the selections made, or pass them in the url.

Comment: "didn't work" *how*?  What happens?  In what way does it fail?  Is there an error in the PHP logs?  Is the redirect response returned to the client?  What URL does it specify?  What happens when that URL is requested?

Comment: Can PHP can evaluate the `<?php ?>` tags in your `header()` call? I hope not. Try stating something like `header("Location: delete/delete.product.php?product=".$encodeCodeProduct);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to redirect to onother page after if condition is satified in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231254/how-to-redirect-to-onother-page-after-if-condition-is-satified-in-php)

Comment: No, the `<?php` tags are not processed, but that's not the only technical issue. Apart from that it's clear what goes wrong and what the exact goal is, apart from any concrete errors in this code. In addition, 'delete' urls are generally not a very good idea, and it may be smarter to implement the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/8782153/8317956

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation:** You can't Append PHP inside the PHP tag. Hence you need to Resolve the Error as below. You have to concatenate the PHP with the Header Location Redirect.

```
if($ac == "yes"){
    $message="Demo sold their product";
    header( "Location: delete/delete.product.php?product=".$encodeCodeProduct); die;
} else{
    $message="Demo did not sell their product";
    header( "Location: delete/delete.product.php?product=".$encodeCodeProduct); die;
}
```

**Error Would Likely Occur:** If you face the Header Already Sent Error you have to clear the outputs that has been sent already with the help of `ob_start()` before the header Redirection.

Redirection code with ob_start

```
if($ac == "yes"){
    $message="Demo sold their product";
    ob_start();
    header( "Location: delete/delete.product.php?product=".$encodeCodeProduct); die;
} else{
    $message="Demo did not sell their product";
    ob_start();
    header( "Location: delete/delete.product.php?product=".$encodeCodeProduct); die;
}
```

More Additional Reference from SO: [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You are already inside PHP tags, so in your location string, you can not reopen PHP tags when you want to write `$encodeCodeProduct`. Just write `"...product=$encodeCodeProduct"`, or, `"...product=" . $encodeCodeProduct`.